# Store data with Login form (for each user) - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm building a website with several "zones", to make it easy to understand.
The users will choose any zone they want to go in the login form, they can go any zone they want, but can only choose on login.

---

```
Email: [__________]

Pass:  [__________]

Zone:  [_dropdown_]
         zone 1
         zone 2
          ...
```

---

And I want to actually STORE the zone in the default USERS table when they do login, in the same form (althoug the login form doesnt store anything, as far as I know)

I dont know what files I need to edit, they must be core files...

I've tried to modify default Controllers but no luck. In former laravel versions they seem to be less hidden...

```
Table users (default table used in Laravel for Users/Auth/Login)
-id
-name
-email
-password
-zone (NEW FIELD)
```

It is completely necessary that the "zone" field gets modified each time users login, as the entire website will change depending on this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your zone dropdown's name is `zone`, then in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` paste in the following:

```php
/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'zone' => 'required|in:zone_1,zone_2,zone_3', // all possible zones
    ]);
}

/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user->zone = $request->zone; // update zone in user
    $user->save(); // save user
}
```

Comment: What if I take the zone names from a table (thats what I did) and those zones keep on increasing?
The dropdown on login controller already works and takes the data of a table.

Comment: You can create a method on your model called `zones()` then `return Zone::pluck('title')->toArray();` (if you have a Zone model?) then use it in your validation as `'zone' => Rule::in(\App\User::zones())` (I used title, not sure how your zones table looks like?)

Comment: @Josep Feixas don’t understand or what?

Comment: Hi, it was the weekend so I stopped for two days :)
Sorry but that gave me an error.
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::validateLogin() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

Comment: Edit: yess, it works now, I needed to add "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" above the LoginController.php file.
Thank you, upvoted!

Comment: By the way finally I only used the function "authenticated" below, I really dont need to validate the dropdown as it will always have a valid value selected coming from the database (integer as id)

Answer (score 0):

in Your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` file there is one

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'zone' => $data['zone']
    ]);
}
```

Dont forget To include `zone` in method validator above

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

Then When User Logs In method `authenticated` runs.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // Store Zone In session HERE
}
```

hope this Helps. Feel free to upvote if you find this answer helpfull

Comment: In which file is the function authenticated below? I dont find it.
Also, the users will not choose or set the zone when registering. Only when logging in.